# An example in Murphy's $C^*$- algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

I was told to check that in this example the Gelfand representation is non-isometry nor surjective. So I'm trying to write a proof for it.

My attempt:

Our Gelfand representation is  $\phi: A \rightarrow C_0(\Omega(A))$, defined by $a \rightarrow \hat{a}$, where $\Omega(A)$ is the set of characters on $A$.

Show it's non-isometry: we want to show $\|\phi a\|= \| \hat{a}\| \ne \| a\|$. This is equivalent to showing that the map is not injective, i.e $Ker(\phi)\ne \{0 \}$. I feel like somehow I need to use that if $f' \in A$, then $f' \in C([0,1])$ to show the kernel is not zero. But I'm not sure what to do from here.

Show it's not surjective: We want to find $\hat{a} \in C_0(\Omega(A)) $ such that nothing in $A$ will be mapped to $\hat{a}$. I'm not sure how to proceed, Again I feel like I'm missing something from that  $f' \in C([0,1])$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You won't get anywhere without first identifying what $\Omega(A)$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to see that the arguments that show that $\Omega(C[0,1])$ are the pointwise evaluations still work for $\Omega(A)$.

Now you can take the $x$ from the example (the identity). You have $\|x\|=2$, $\|\hat x\|=1$. So the Gelfand transform is not an isometry. It is injective, though.

If $f\in C[0,1]$ is not differentiable, it cannot be the image of some $g\in A$. This is because the characters are the point evaluations: if $f=\phi(g)$ we would have, for any $a\in[0,1]$,
$$
g(a)=a(g)=\hat g(a)=f(a).
$$
So $\phi$ is not surjective.

Comment: May I ask how you got $g(a)=a(g)=\hat g(a)=f(a)$? Isn't $a$ a constant? Why do we have $g(a)=a(g)$? Also, for the second equity, do we have $a$ as a homomorphism now? Thanks!

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, the characters are precisely the point-evaluations. So the point $a$, as a character, evaluated at $g$, is $g(a)$.

Comment: Is it obvious that the characters are the point-evaluations? May I ask how you got that the characters are the point-evaluations? Thank you so much!

Comment: No, it's not obvious. Like I wrote in the first paragraph, it can be done in the same way as in the case of $C[0,1]$.